# Why isn't my keyring in Ubuntu working?

Tags: gnome, ssh, keyrings, ssh-agent

I have encrypted my `id_rsa` with a password. I think Ubuntu has a keyring system which prevents me from inputting password every time I have to use `id_rsa`, `like git push`. Sometimes I don't need to type in the password, sometimes I do.

When I execute

```
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

$ gnome-keyring import ~/.ssh/id_rsa
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /run/user/1000/keyring-wUoO5j/pkcs11: Connection refused
p11-kit: gnome-keyring: module failed to initialize, skipping: An error occurred on the device
gnome-keyring: couldn't find any place to import files

$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK 
/run/user/1000/keyring-wUoO5j/ssh
$ echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
<empty>
```

In seahorse, the key is listed in openssh keys

Does any body has the same problem? Or how to solve this?

Comment: check the keyring, if your key is there. It is called `seahorse` or `gnome-keyring`. From this report is not possible to understand if it is working or not. If it does not work from some terminal window, check if you have available using `ssh-add -l`.

Comment: @Jakuje $ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: What about `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `echo $SSH_AGENT_PID`. Is the agent not responding, or you fiddled with environment variables? Does it work after reboot?

Comment: @Jakuje after reboot, it is going to work for a while, but it will stop working again.

Comment: When you get this error run this `ps aux | grep keyring` to see if the daemon is up and running!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Gnome services such as `gnome-keyring-daemon` and `gnome-settings-daemon` are not running when you are logged in.

AFAIR you can change this: choose `settings > settings manager > session and startup > advanced` and enable `Gnome services`

Another way to avoid typing in your password every time, is to use the following commands **once after system startup in a terminal**

```
ssh-agent

ssh-add <add path if not standard key>
```

you will be prompted for your password to your key and the agent will store it until next reboot.

HTH,

s1mmel

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar issue (I'm using ElementaryOS), where I had to enter my key's password every time I used it in the terminal.  It used to ask me for the password via the GUI and kept that in memory for a while, but this somehow stopped working.

I tried many of the suggestions found by Googling this (eg. adjust deamon config via gconf-settings, checked startup applications, add to .bashrc, install keychain, ..) but to no avail.

I did find [this article on Cup of Linux](http://www.cupoflinux.com/SBB/index.php?topic=3292.0) which suggested checking the pam.d settings in `/etc/pam.d/`.  Since my configuration was definitely different as in the article, I search for `pam_gnome_keyring` and commented all occurences in all files of the lines

```
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

After a reboot / relogin, I was finally asked by the GUI again for the password..

grep before changes:

```
:~$ grep -r pam_gnome_keyring /etc/pam.d/
/etc/pam.d/common-password:password optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

grep after changes (note the # in the last 4 lines):

```
:~$ grep -r pam_gnome_keyring /etc/pam.d/
/etc/pam.d/common-password:password optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:#auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter:#session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:#auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
/etc/pam.d/lightdm:#session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```